# Importing raster files EPSG:3035 (ETRS89, LAEA) into R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

My knowledge of both R and QGIS is not very high.

I have a problem with the European DEM layer (25 m resolution) downloaded from the COPERNICUS website. The reference system is EPSG:3035 (ETRS89, LAEA).

I cannot import the raster file into R. It doesn't recognise it as a raster file. It says the file does not exist even though it is present as a .TIF file. The error message at the following script line:

```r
library(raster)

# the file is exactly in that folder
dem <- raster("RSF/eu_dem_v11_E30N20.tif") 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer", :
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
In addition: Warning message:
  RSF/eu_dem_v11_E30N20.tif: No such file or directory (GDAL error 4)
```

Comment: The error message at the following script line:
dem <- raster("RSF/eu_dem_v11_E30N20.tif") #the file is exactly in that folder
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer", :
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
In addition: Warning message:
RSF/eu_dem_v11_E30N20.tif: No such file or directory (GDAL error 4)

Comment: Kindly add the full code and error message in your post by editing it rather mentioning in comment.

Comment: If it says "file does not exist" then first thing to do is make sure the file does exist. What does `file.exists("RSF/eu_dem_v11_E30N20.tif")` say? `TRUE` or `FALSE`? The file may be in a folder with that name but is R starting from the folder above?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Ok. sorry. I modified the question ;-)

Comment: @Spacedman it is effectively FALSE. I deleted the folder name in the path and it returns TRUE. It was probably as you said. Thanks... I didn't know about the file.exists function

Comment: File paths like that are relative to wherever R has run from, which you can get with the `getwd()` function, unless something has changed it (with the `setwd()` function).